# React Native Facebook SDK Next - null is not an object (evaluating 'Settings.initializeSDK')

Tags: android, react-native, facebook-sdk-4.0, fbsdk, react-native-fbsdk

I am trying to integrate facebook sdk into my react native app with a goal of optimizing app installs through the fb ads.

I followed all the steps mentioned here

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fbsdk-next
- https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts/487102509986353/?platform=android

But while trying to initialise sdk via
`Settings.initializeSDK()` ( as mentioned in the usage section) getting the following error.
`null is not an object (evaluating 'Settings.initializeSDK')` in the native android build.

P.S. : I am using Expo, bare workflow.

What is going wrong? Also, do we need to use `Settings.initializeSDK()` for fb to track app installs?

Comment: Hey, don't know if you figured this out, but you have to `import { Settings } from 'react-native-fbsdk-next';`

Comment: @PelayoMartinez Thanks, I had done the same. Expo integration and then expo eject helped me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by deleting the android/ios folders since i was using expo. Then make changes as advised for Expo in the documentation and expo eject.
The auto generated config worked out well