# React Native: 'FBSDKApplicationDelegate' undeclared identifier error in AppDelegate.mm

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-fbsdk

Im building a react native app and Im trying to install and set up the [fbsdk-next](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fbsdk-next) pack and have followed the steps multiple times now but still get the same error: `error: use of undeclared identifier 'FBSDKApplicationDelegate' if ([[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:app openURL:url options:options]) { ^`

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74139714/react-native-facebook-sdk-next-null-is-not-an-object-evaluating-settings-ini) solution but still the same error..

My AppDelegate.mm file looks like this:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <AuthenticationServices/AuthenticationServices.h>
#import <SafariServices/SafariServices.h>
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit-Swift.h>
#import <React/RCTLinkingManager.h>

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
            options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options
{
  if ([[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:app openURL:url options:options]) {
    return YES;
  }

  if ([RCTLinkingManager application:app openURL:url options:options]) {
    return YES;
  }
  
  return NO;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  self.moduleName = @"AppName";
  // You can add your custom initial props in the dictionary below.
  // They will be passed down to the ViewController used by React Native.
  self.initialProps = @{};

  return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}

- (NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
  return [self getBundleURL];
}

- (NSURL *)getBundleURL
{
#if DEBUG
  return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index"];
#else
  return [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
#endif
}

@end
```

and I have this in my Info.plist:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>fb<my-id></string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>$(CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION)</string>
    <key>FacebookAppID</key>
    <string><my-id></string>
    <key>FacebookClientToken</key>
    <string><my-token></string>
    <key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
    <string><app-name></string>
    <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>fbapi</string>
        <string>fb-messenger-share-api</string>
    </array>
```

I've added the linking manually aswell:

```
pod 'react-native-fbsdk-next', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-fbsdk-next'
```

and tried the other way:

```
installer.aggregate_targets.first.user_project.native_targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS'] = ['$(inherited)', '$(SDKROOT)/usr/lib/swift']
      end
    end
```

Anyone have a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <AuthenticationServices/AuthenticationServices.h>
#import <SafariServices/SafariServices.h>
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit-Swift.h>
#import <React/RCTLinkingManager.h>

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
            options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options
{
  if ([[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:app openURL:url options:options]) {
    return YES;
  }

  if ([RCTLinkingManager application:app openURL:url options:options]) {
    return YES;
  }
  
  return NO;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  self.moduleName = @"AppName";
  // You can add your custom initial props in the dictionary below.
  // They will be passed down to the ViewController used by React Native.
  self.initialProps = @{};

 [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                   didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions]

  return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}

- (NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
  return [self getBundleURL];
}

- (NSURL *)getBundleURL
{
#if DEBUG
  return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index"];
#else
  return [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
#endif
}

@end
```

You have missed to initialize the SDK inside the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but that just got me another error: 
error: use of undeclared identifier 'FBSDKApplicationDelegate'
  [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application

Comment: That is weird, It seems the library is not properly linked.